# Does ASP.NET Core feature a built-in OAuth2 token exchange?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, oauth-2.0

I'm building an ASP.NET Core application and using [FusionAuth](https://fusionauth.io/) as my authentication server. I'm trying to implement this [authorization grant workflow](https://fusionauth.io/learn/expert-advice/authentication/spa/oauth-authorization-code-grant-jwts-refresh-tokens-cookies/), with an SPA using JWT bearer tokens. To summarize, once the user authenticates with FusionAuth, the frontend is supposed to redirect to the backend server with an authorization code. My backend server then needs to receive this code at a special endpoint. Inside this endpoint it will perform a call to FusionAuth again, but this time with the client secret which only the server will possess. In turn, FusionAuth will send back an authorization token in the form of a JWT and a refresh token, which my server then needs to return back to the frontend.

I've looked at the [.AddOAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.oauthextensions.addoauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0) method, and having read the code it seems capable of performing the token exchange. However, it also has a lot of logic involving challenges and login/logout. This makes me think it's supposed to be used for cookie-based server-side authentication, like you would find with Razor pages.

All I want to do is set up my server to be this authentication intermediary. It looks like `.AddOAuth()` might do this for me, but it may not be intended for this purpose. I can't find any examples of folks using `.AddJwt(...)` and `.AddOAuth(...)` in conjunction. Is there a mechanism in ASP.NET Core that performs the token exchange?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using IdentityModel? It's not part of ASP.NET Core, but it is open source. I found it useful when implementing the authorization code grant in ASP.NET core.

Here is some documentation that may be helpful:

https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetcore/web.html

Answer (score -3):

The short answer is yes - see [Introduction to Identity on Asp.NET CORE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio). There are lots of flavors of OAuth 2, which means it can be configured in many ways. You will need to read the docs.

Comment: You don't appear to understand OP's question (they don't just want to add OAuth as an authentication method to their SPA), and "here are the generic docs, go read them so you might find what you need" never has been a good answer.

Comment: And yet, sometimes "read the documents" is the only answer to a general question.  Asp.NET Core has rich support for OAuth that goes well beyond using it as an authentication method for a SPA. To understand how to apply the technology one has to know exactly what is being attempted. It can be very difficult for a beginner to even express the question in a way that will allow other people to help, without first doing some research themselves.

Comment: If you believe "go read the docs" is an answer to the question, your answer may be better off as a comment.